# How to read an INI file entirley?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to read an INI file entirely, I am using `wxFileConfig` class to do that but the most examples of the internet just to reading & writing only an item, not an entire INI file.

The data in the INI file similar to the following:

```
[sdl]
fullresolution=0x0
fullscreen=true
output=opengl
autolock=false

[dosbox]
machine=svga_s3
memsize=16

[render]
frameskip=0
aspect=false
scaler=normal2x

[cpu]
core=normal
cputype=auto
cycles=10000
cycleup=1000
cycledown=1000
.....
```

I tried to do something, but it just reads the headers ([sdl], [dosbox], [render], ...).

```
wxFileConfig config(wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxGetCwd() + "\\dosbox.conf");
wxString str;
long idx;
bool bCont = config.GetFirstGroup(str, idx);
while (bCont) {
    bCont = config.GetNextGroup(str, idx);
    debugMsg("%s", str);
}
```

**How to read each header with its items?**

Comment: Are you trying to get the entries for a single header or are you trying to read all the headers and items separately?

Comment: @DeveloperPaul:  read all the headers and items.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_config_base.html#aaca0748de0e2e2841aaec85f63403d3b) you can read all the entries like so:

```cpp
// enumeration variables
wxString str;
long dummy;

// first enum all entries
bool bCont = config->GetFirstEntry(str, dummy);
while ( bCont ) {
    aNames.Add(str);
    bCont = config->GetNextEntry(str, dummy);
}
```

It's very similar to the code you have to read the all the groups.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have seen that documentation and used that code before but doesn't get any item.

Comment: @LionKing, can you step thru the code and see where does it fail? Also, what version of wx you are using and whats your OS?

Comment: Thank you, but your code is part of the complete code and the code that I supplied in my question is also part, but the complete code I have written in a new answer and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I found a complete code that brings all data from an `.ini` file:

```
wxFileConfig config(wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxGetCwd() + "\\dosbox.conf");
wxString group;
long group_index;

config.SetPath("/");
bool has_group = config.GetFirstGroup(group, group_index);
while (has_group) {
    config.SetPath(group);

    wxString entry;
    long entry_index;

    bool has_entry = config.GetFirstEntry(entry, entry_index);
    while (has_entry) {
        wxString value = config.Read(entry, "");
        wxMessageOutputDebug d;
        d.Printf("[%s] %s = %s", group, entry, value);

        has_entry = config.GetNextEntry(entry, entry_index);
    }

    config.SetPath("/");
    has_group = config.GetNextGroup(group, group_index);
}
```

[The source](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=189866#p189866).